# Pivot table and creaation of additional columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
    P   G   N   B   A  
0 NaN   3   6 NaN NaN  
1 NaN   2   8 NaN NaN  
2   4 NaN NaN NaN NaN  
3 NaN NaN NaN   7 12  
4 NaN   5   9 NaN NaN
```

I would like to transform it in this one:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  
0 NaN NaN NaN   G NaN NaN   N NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN   G NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   N NaN NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN   P NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 
3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   B NaN NaN NaN NaN   A  
4 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   G NaN NaN NaN   N NaN NaN NaN
```

Any efficient way to do it?

Comment: Please post what you tried, we're not a code-writing service.